# PL/SQL data type support for size greater than NVarchar2

Tags: asp.net, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

PL/SQL has data type NVARCHAR2(size) where the size is 32767 bytes; equivalent to 4095 records.

Now, what data type should i give as an alternative to NVARCHAR2 that could support more than 4k records? I have a gridview in asp.net that doesn't support paging. Which datatype is most suitable to support more than 4095 records?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this just text? You could use [`CLOB`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF20041):

> The `CLOB` data type stores single-byte and multibyte character data.
>   Both fixed-width and variable-width character sets are supported, and
>   both use the database character set. `CLOB` objects can store up to (4
>   gigabytes -1) * (the value of the `CHUNK` parameter of `LOB` storage) of
>   character data. If the tablespaces in your database are of standard
>   block size, and if you have used the default value of the `CHUNK`
>   parameter of `LOB` storage when creating a `LOB` column, then this is
>   equivalent to (4 gigabytes - 1) * (database block size).

You can check [same page](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF20041) for other types (`BLOB`, `NCLOB`) for storing large amounts of data.

Comment: thanks for the info. But taking such a huge datatype would decrease the page performance as sending such huge data (over network from web application) would incurse an overhead on network and server also.

Comment: @Xor power, it says "up to", you don't have to store 4GB in the variable. You asked for storage larger than 32K and NullUserExecption provided you the answer. Surely you can't then complain that it's too much storage?